# Items Submitted Through Workflow In Awaiting Approval Status Are Publishing To Both Preview And Web

Tags: publishing, workflow, publishing-service

I have a really strange problem. I have a Sitecore 8.2 site that has preview and web publishing targets. I expect that when a user Submits an item through Workflow, when it is in Awaiting Approval Status, it is published to preview only. However, it is publishing to both preview and web! If I publish items manually and select the publishing target, publishing works as expected.

Here is what I have done so far to no avail:

Checked the box for "Preview publishing target" on the Preview Publish Target item (as described in the [Sitecore Documentation](https://doc.sitecore.com/users/82/sitecore-experience-platform/en/publishing-items-to-a-preview-publishing-target.html))
[image: Preview Publishing Target Settings]

Checked the box for the preview publishing target on the Awaiting Approval Workflow State (as described in the [Sitecore Documentation](https://doc.sitecore.com/users/82/sitecore-experience-platform/en/publishing-items-to-a-preview-publishing-target.html))
[image: Awaiting Approval Workflow State Settings]

Contacted Sitecore Support, they instructed me to do the following (which is not stated in the [Sitecore Documentation](https://doc.sitecore.com/users/82/sitecore-experience-platform/en/publishing-items-to-a-preview-publishing-target.html)). Doing this caused the issue where publishing to preview would also publish items in Awaiting Approval status to web.

1. Navigate to "/sitecore/system/Workflows/JHM Health Standard Workflow/Awaiting Approval" item
2. Right click "Insert" -> "insert from template"
3. Select "templates/System/Workflow/Action" template and provide appropriate name for item (Auto Publish to Preview)
4. In the "Type String" field, set the value to : "Sitecore.Workflows.Simple.PublishAction, Sitecore.Kernel"
5. In the "Parameters" field, set the value to : "deep=1&smart=1"

Any ideas on what I am missing here? Your help is much appreciated!

Comment: can you please try by adding targets=preview in your publish action parameter?

Comment: Thank you, that did it!

Answer (score 2):

OOTB Auto publish in the workflow is design for the final workflow state, code within is it will always pick the all the database under `/sitecore/system/publishing targets` if we have not defined the targets in parameter -

```
 private IEnumerable<Database> GetTargets(
  NameValueCollection parameters,
  Item actionItem,
  Item dataItem)
{
  using (new SecurityDisabler())
  {
    IEnumerable<string> source = this.GetEnumerableValue("targets", parameters, actionItem);
    if (!source.Any<string>())
    {
      Item obj = dataItem.Database.Items["/sitecore/system/publishing targets"];
      if (obj != null)
        source = obj.Children.Select<Item, string>((Func<Item, string>) (child => child["Target database"])).Where<string>((Func<string, bool>) (dbName => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(dbName)));
    }
    foreach (string str in source)
    {
      string databaseName = str;
      Database database = Factory.GetDatabase(databaseName, false);
      if (database != null)
        yield return database;
      else
        Log.Warn("Unknown database in PublishAction: " + databaseName, (object) this);
      databaseName = (string) null;
    }
  }
}
```

if you want to do an auto-publish on a specific database either you need to pass the targets or need to create your custom auto-publish just to pick all the database you need in non-final state of the workflow. In your case parameter will be like -

```
"deep=1&smart=1&targets=preview"
```